# how to get only child records when all are equal too 100 percentage mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Parent PROJECT table:**

```
GUID name
1       Prd_1
2       Prd_2
3       Prd_3
```

**Child MILESTONE table**

```
GUID  PROJECT_GUID percentage 
1        1    90
2        1    100
3        2    50
4        3    100
```

My  current query:

> returns project 1 and 3 in fact it should only return me project 3

```
select `NAME`,GOAL, COMPLETION_DATE  from `PROJECT`  Prj
INNER JOIN MILESTONE Ms
ON Prj.GUID = Ms.PROJECT_GUID
WHERE `PERCENT_COMPLETE` = 100
group by `NAME`, GOAL, COMPLETION_DATE
ORDER BY `COMPLETION_DATE`;
```

any help please thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation functions like `SUM()` or `MAX()`?

Comment: Most of the columns in your query aren't in the tables you show. Please make them consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that checks of the project has any percentages that are *not* 100, and filters them out.

```
SELECT *
FROM Project p
JOIN Milestone m ON p.GUID = m.Project_GUID
WHERE p.GUID NOT IN (
    SELECT Project_GUID
    FROM Milestone
    WHERE Percent_Complete != 100
)
```

If you want the final completion date of any projects where all milestones are completed, you can use:

```
SELECT p.Name, MAX(m.date_complete) AS date_complete
FROM Project AS p
JOIN Milestone AS m on p.GUID = m.Project_GUID
GROUP BY p.GUID
HAVING MIN(m.Percent_Complete) = 100
```

Comment: this one gives me duplicate records

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Comment: But I need more columns could you please add this to your answer thanks

Comment: I'm selecting all the columns. If you want to select specific columns, replace it with that.

Comment: gotcha! thanks. could you please explain your query a little bit for me. this one actually works I just need to know how you doing it. thanks.

Comment: If a project only has 100% completion, that means there are no rows with any other completion value. So we get all the milestones with not-100%, and exclude those projects with `NOT IN`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206991/discussion-between-muhammad-and-barmar).

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tS5QFNzE27K7EmL11APCRM/2 could you please check this

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function for a single column, it applies to the entire `SELECT` list. You don't have any duplicates, the rows have different completion dates because they're different milestones.

Comment: If you just want the date of the final milestone, use `MAX(date_complete)` and `GROUP BY p.GUID`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the WHERE clause and use HAVING:

```
SELECT `NAME`, GOAL, COMPLETION_DATE  
FROM `PROJECT`  Prj INNER JOIN MILESTONE Ms
ON Prj.GUID = Ms.PROJECT_GUID
GROUP BY `NAME`, GOAL, COMPLETION_DATE
HAVING MIN(Ms.`PERCENT_COMPLETE`) = 100
ORDER BY `COMPLETION_DATE`;
```

I assume that the maximum value in column `PERCENT_COMPLETE` is 100.
Also it's a good practice to qualify all the columns with the table name/alias they belong.

Comment: It works for the sample data that you posted. Check the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tS5QFNzE27K7EmL11APCRM/0

Comment: see this one gives me wrong record https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tS5QFNzE27K7EmL11APCRM/1

Comment: Of course it gives you wrong results because you group by PERCENT_COMPLETE which is wrong. I don't have this grouping in my code. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tS5QFNzE27K7EmL11APCRM/3

Comment: Also I use GOAL, COMPLETION_DATE in GROUP BY in my query because it exists in your code and I assumed that these columns are in the table PROJECT.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample You could use a subquery for min perc for  a project  =   100

```
select  * from PROJECT p
inner  join  (
  select PROJECT_GUID, min(percentage ) min_percentage 
  from MILESTONE 
  group by  PROJECT_GUID
  having count(*) = count(distinct percentage)
) t on t.PROJECT_GUID = p.GUID 
where min_percentage  = 100
```